# How to return instance of Error using Spring REST call

Tags: spring, rest, error-handling

In my front end application, I have to handle the error response of the HTTP REST call.

Front end:

```
  restservice.check().subscribe(
                response => {
                    if (response != null) {

                    },
                error => {

                    if (error instanceof Error) {

                    }}
                        });
```

Controller.java

public ResponseEntity updateEstablishment
                     {

```
                 return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus.OK);
                 }

                 How can I return an instance of Error here.
```

Answer (score 0):

REST services should catch and handle internal exception. And should return meaningful error code and message back to client. Please find below link to best way to handle exception in REST
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-error-handling-best-practices